# Query PostgreSQL for a log directory/filename

Tags: postgresql, logging

In the PostgreSQL shell I can type:

```
SHOW log_directory
```

and I can see where the log file is saved.

The question is - is there a `SELECT` statement which will give me the same information?

TIA!

Comment: Since Postgres 10 you can also query the current logfile: `select pg_current_logfile()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these two are  equivalent:

```
knayak=# show log_directory;
log_directory
---------------
 log
(1 row)

knayak=# select setting FROM pg_settings where name = 'log_directory';
 setting
---------
 log
(1 row)
```